# Basic authourization using fetch or http.get methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an endpoint and credentials and I don't want these credentials to be encoded. I want a response from the endpoint when I hit it. I got a JSON response(which had only 1 object with 4 keys and corresponding values) when I hit this endpoint using postman. How do I code this thing in Node.Js to get the same JSON response I am unable to get the JSON response.

```
var request = require('request');
const url = "Myendpoint url"; // endpoint is working in postman
```

// Below credentials are correct as I have used them postman

```
const auth = {          
   username : "xxxxxxx", 
   password : "xxxxxxx"
}         

request.get(url,auth,function(err,response,data){
   if (!err && response.statuscode === 200)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response); // Is this the right way get JSON response output ?  
});
```

When I use fetch, I got `"First certificate not verified"` error message. I used `request.get()` but unable to get the JSON response object which I got in postman

Answer (score 0):

Please change auth in `request.get(url,auth,function...` to be `request.get(url,{auth},function ...` if it not working try the below two options

```
  var username = 'fooUsername'
  var password = 'fooPassword'
  var options = {
      url: 'http://localhost:1234/api/res/xyz',
      auth: {
          user: username,
          password: password
        }
    }

  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
       if (err) {
         console.dir(err)
        return
    }
   console.dir('headers', res.headers)
   console.dir('status code', res.statusCode)
    console.dir(body)
 })
```

Or

```
  const username = 'username',
            password = 'password',
       url = 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@some.server.com';

    request({url}, function (error, response, body) {
        // Do more stuff with 'body' here
     });
```